# Cannot insert JavaScript variable into Jade

Tags: meteor, pug

I'm trying to insert a normal JavaScript expression into a Jade file. But my app keep getting error message when I add `isAccepted` variable into my code.This is the error message.

> Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.
>
> Errors prevented startup:
>
> While building the application:
>   jade-test.jade: Jade syntax error: Expected identifier, number, string, >boolean, or null
>   {{isAccepted ? 'class1' : 'class2...
>                ^
>   packages/compileJade/plugin/handler.js:44:1: Cannot read property 'head' >of undefined (compiling jade-test.jade) (at fileModeHandler)
>
> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

This is my code:

jade-test.jade

```
template(name="layout")
  h1 This is layout template
  h2 This is h2 paragraph
  h3 This is h3 paragraph
   +hello

template(name="hello")
  h4 This is home template
  button Click me
  p You have click me #{counter} times.
  - var isAccepted = true
  button(class=isAccepted ? 'class1' : 'class2') I'm the right choice.
```

jade-test.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    }
  });

  Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('layout');
  });
 }

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if inserting javascript code like this in jade is supported, you should probably use a helper instead.

I don't think the ternary expression syntax is valid too, again, use a helper.

JADE

```
template(name="hello")
  h4 This is home template
  button Click me
  p You have click me #{counter} times.
  button(class=isAccepted) I'm the right choice.
```

JS

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  isAccepted: function(){
    var isAccepted = true;
    return isAccepted ? "class1" : "class2";
  }
});
```

Comment: @ saimeunt, I follow the guide from this page: http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/. Which says: All the normal JavaScript expressions work fine too: `- var authenticated = true  body(class=authenticated ? 'authed' : 'anon')`

Comment: I guess `meteor-jade` is only a subset of the whole Jade syntax and you can't use this feature anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use another syntax.